# Java process mem is less as compared to shown in grafana

Tags: java, grafana, heap-dump

In my Java microservice, the heap dump is showing around 122 MB of memory whereas the Grafana is showing around 1.2G of memory usage. I'm not able to find the leak or why this difference is. Also, the pod memory in Grafana is linearly increasing.

The metrics I monitor is the POD memory as shown in the image

[image]

Comment: Could you mention the exact metrics and their names, that you mointor in Grafana? It could be that the metrics you take into account contain additional information e.g. like the memory used by the Operating System in POD.

Comment: @ApostolosEmmanouilidis I have updated the question. I hope this will help you to understand it more better.

Comment: The JVM consumes more memory than just the heap, there is also native memory, and the metaspace, and memory for GC metadata, etc. Also there is a difference between allocated memory, and actual memory *in use*.